# .httacces custom redirectioning

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all invalid traffic to my index page.
Invalid traffic in this context means:

-Case 1. Nonexistent directories

-Case 2. Nonexistent files

-Case 3. Existing route but only directory: Like in example "validroute/images" or "validroute/images/"

Actually my **working** code is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R,L,QSA]

Options -Indexes
```

For cases 1 and 2 the conditions and the RewriteRule are redirecting correctly to my index.php
For the third case Im using the "Options -indexes" which avoids user to browse my directory and displays the forbidden error. I want to redirect this last case also to the index.php instead.

The nearest approach i got based on [redirect 403 error using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444359/redirect-403-error-using-htaccess/24081261)  was this

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

Instead of redirecting ALL forbidden (403) when trying to display a valid "folder" (and ONLY in this case) i seek to redirect to index.

By setting the same redirects i expect the user not to be able to see my directories even if he tries to manually input different routes to see if the directory exists or not. Actually he has the hint because some are "forbidden" and others redirects to index.

This is NOT a duplicate of these because given answers didn't fit me or the issues are not what I intend:

[.htaccess redirect - Options -Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684735/htaccess-redirect-options-indexes)

[.htaccess option -indexes redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960241/htaccess-option-indexes-redirect)

[.htaccess to redirect everything to index.php, but keep a copy of the website in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322909/htaccess-to-redirect-everything-to-index-php-but-keep-a-copy-of-the-website-in)

Maybe is not possible at all or maybe there is another command or maybe a proper regex combined to RewriteRule to fix the selection.

Comment: Explain how the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22960453/1427878 is not working for you then. (You might want to remove the `R=301` flag of course, because you do not want an external redirect at this point. Either issue 403 status code via the `R` flag, or let whatever script you rewrite this to do it.)

Comment: I'm struggling to see what you are trying to achieve here? If you "redirect" everything to `index.php` then you have just a single webpage and no static resources (because everything is redirected)? "but DO NOT PREVENT NAVIGATION/BROWSING the contents" - but that "working" rule does prevent navigating/browsing the contents?!

Comment: @CBroe the redirecting from that answer ONLY works when i use a bad directory, but not on a correct one, for example localhost/index.php works, localhost/images/background.jpg works. But if i try localhost/pictures/background.jpg it will send me to index thanks to the 2 first lines, but if i try to navigate to localhost/pictures/ IT IS browsing the contents of this folder which is what im struggling with

Comment: @MrWhite i only want to redirect directory browsing and wrong paths, not everything. By browsing the contents i meant "see all the different files and folders i have stored there". I mean, i can see it like its a windows folder. With an example  if /domain/images/test.jpg is accessible, but /domain/images/ should not display ALL the image files that i stored there

Comment: _"but if i try to navigate to localhost/pictures/ IT IS browsing the contents"_ - because you have not implemented a check for "request matches _existing_ directory" yet, only the opposite. _"but if i try localhost/pictures/background.jpg it will send me to index thanks to the 2 first lines"_ - if that is not what you want, and this is supposed to be an existing file - then you need to amend the check before that rule by one that checks it does not match an existing file either, currently you are only checking it does not match an existing directory.

Comment: "if /domain/images/test.jpg is accessible" - Although with the "working" rule you've posted, `test.jpg` would _not_ be accessible?

Comment: Do you ever want to access the `DirectoryIndex` document in a directory by requesting just that directory? eg. Should `/subdirectory/` serve `/subdirectory/index.php` or will you always request `/subdirectory/index.php` directly? Or does that not apply (ie. you are not using `index.php` etc. at all in subdirectories)?

Comment: @CBroe im trying to cover both cases: 1.When the directory doesn't exist  (first 2 lines working fine) 2.When the directory does exist but i dont want the user to peek the contents or the structure. For number 2 i got the forbidden working but i would like a direct reddirection instead.

Comment: @MrWhite "Although with the "working" rule you've posted, test.jpg would not be accessible? " Seems not, that is why i put extra effort in saying that i already tried those, i fail to understand where im going wrong for my purposes. At the moment i can use /directoryindex/subdirectory/file.php i can use that direct uri, but i want to restrict being able to "/directoryindex/subdirectory/"  alone because that displays too much information

Comment: "Seems not" - In that case, you must have some other directives or some other config that is affecting this (eg. a front end proxy that serves your static resources perhaps?). The "first 2 lines" state... for any request that does not map to a physical directory, redirect to `index.php`. That includes static files. (In other words, by itself, that first rule doesn't really make much sense.)

Comment: Regarding the 403 Forbidden. That is triggered by mod_autoindex. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/138221/1243) to the following question on the [Webmasters stack](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) to prevent this particular 403 response: [Create a virtual index file to prevent 403s](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138217/create-a-virtual-index-file-to-prevent-403s)

Comment: @MrWhite i will take a look into it, good bunch of info and a different approach. If i manage to solve my issue i will post it here anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a layer above for the server at which i am not able to access or to see in any way, but as i was handling other kind of permissions (folder accesses by password) i noticed that this had its own way of working without allowing developer to modify this.
So i guess there is no way to override such from a higher lvl .htaccess without direct access to server.
I was using Plesk Obsidian.

So if you dont have full control on the server your configurations might generate some conflicts.